# Why does one child div not fill its height when others do?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of nested divs that look as so:
[Nested divs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AAB0.png)

HTML and CSS are below. As you can see from the image, though, the top right div (`.inner-top-mark`) does not fill its entire height. I have already determined that this can be resolved by setting this div's `display:` to `flex`, `table`, or `inline-block`. My question is simply *why* this happens when the `.inner-bottom-opts` divs do not have this same problem. I have seen a few similar questions floating around, but none seem to address the why aspect, and the particular solution for each person asking seems to vary on a case-by-case basis, thus it's not helpful to prevent future problems.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="part1_labelleft">
    <p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></p>
  </div>

  <div class="part1_markup_right">
    <div class="inner-top-mark">
      <p><em><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong></em></p>
    </div>

    <div class="inner-bottom-opts">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-bottom-opts">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-bottom-opts">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner-bottom-opts">
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  width: 800px;
}
div[class*="labelleft"] {
  display: flex;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
div[class*="labelleft"] p {
  margin: auto 0;
}
.part1_markup_right {
  float: left;
  width: 90%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner-top-mark {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.inner-bottom-opts {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.part1_markup_right p {
  margin: 0.75em 0;
}
.inner-top-mark p {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.part1_markup_right,
.inner-bottom-opts + .inner-bottom-opts{
  border-left: 1px solid #acacac;
}
.inner-top-mark {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #acacac;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
.container {
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you can add this to a JS Fiddle, it would help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your div "inner-top-mark" is in a list of floated elements but it self doesn't float. This is a side effect that causes that your div only have the height of it child elements (in your case the "p").
So if you add float: left or float:inherit to your "inner-top-mark"-div, it will have the right height.